# Is there a better way to cross redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Context: Right now I'm trying to take two redstone inputs and use them, mirrored, on the inside and outside of an XOR gate and an AND gate.

Problem: I am not confident that the method I am using to cross redstone paths without having them connect is the best. This is mostly because of how bulky and it requires extra redstone length.

[image: This is an example of what I wish I could be doing. Please help me find a way to get something that still creates the same result of 2]

XOR (left) AND (right).

This is an example of what I wish I could be doing. Please help me find a way to get something that still creates the same result of 2 redstone inputs.

For more context I am trying to recreate this part of a CLA fast adder, where A_0 is the red wire, and B_0 is the blue wire:

[image: Four bit adder with carry lookahead]

Comment: It's important to tag the version, I suppose this is Java edition

Comment: How much vertical height do you have available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bridge one line over the other. The bridge can be a literal bridge of blocks that goes over one wire and carries the other wire. Alternatively, if you are tight on vertical space and don't mind some delay in the circuit, you can cross the wires like this:
[image: repeater crossing]